# SQL: Outputting From Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, field

Question Posed: `List the people and the schools for people who attended schools in Missouri.`

I have a table called `Post` and a table called `People`. Each person in `people` has a `unitid` that corresponds to a `unitid` in post, basically saying where they go to college at. Each college in `Post` has a `unitid`, and a state abbreviation field, `stabbr`.

I am able to use the following to get the formmated names, and UnitID from `people` but can't figure out how to add on the Universities Name as well. Universities names are `instnm`.

```
select concat_ws(" ",surname,givenname,middleInitial) as 'whole_name',
       unitid 
from people 
where 
       unitid in (select unitid from post where stabbr like 'MO');
```

How Would I go about adding in the university names?

Output:

```
| Kittinger Rita G    | 451316 |
| Cagle Marie P       | 456302 |
| Martinez Shana C    | 460996 |
| Price John O        | 480338 |
| Kurtz Melvin L      | 481580 |
| Olmstead Tabitha J  | 481988 |
| Wynn Stephanie D    | 481997 |
| Garrett Richard L   | 482398 |
| Bell Diane R        | 482398 |
+---------------------+--------+
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server? What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: Umm i believe it's mysql. And I believe a union of some sorts could make it work, I'm just having trouble finding a good example online on how to output it using a query and not making a new table